# Why is NASA redirecting an asteroid to Lunar Orbit instead of LEO?

Tags: asteroid, planning, orion-spacecraft

One of the missions NASA is planning is to redirect a small asteroid to lunar orbit and land astronauts on it.

If it can redirect asteroids, why not just send it to LEO and send a Dragon to it?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does NASA plan to put a meteoroid in Lunar orbit instead of Earth orbit?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/3502/49). Also see [How useful is placing an asteroid in the Moon's orbit?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/4715/49)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that a lunar orbit (specifically, a *distant retrograde orbit* or DRO) is much more stable compared to a low Earth orbit so you can leave it there for a long time and study it in the future. You also don't have to worry about it decaying and colliding with the Earth -- although the size of the target asteroid (actually only a piece of an asteroid) *probably* makes it nothing to worry about.

See [this project](http://ccar.colorado.edu/asen5050/projects/projects_2013/Johnson_Kirstyn/finalorbit.html) for a decent description of DRO's and how they relate to NASA's asteroid redirect mission.

Comment: uhoh link is barroquen! Without the description the answer is a lot less helpful. This is why link-only answers are discouraged. Is it possible to find another link, or at least a better description so it's possible to look for one? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this?  https://scholar.colorado.edu/asen_gradetds/147/  btw I've linked to your answer [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32819/12102)